# How to align the output generated in a shell "for" loop by columns

Tags: bash, text-processing, printf

I'm trying to align output from a bash `for` loop.

Currently, I'm getting output from my loop that looks like so:

```
Directory:  /some/long/directory/path  Remote:  some-remote
Directory:  /some/dir/path  Remote:  other-remote
```

Which I'm trying to align like so:

```
Directory:  /some/long/directory/path  Remote:  some-remote
Directory:  /some/dir/path             Remote:  other-remote
```

The current, basic loop that generates this output looks something like this:

```bash
for dir in $(find /some/path -type d -name .git); do
    cd $dir
    remote=$(git remote)
    printf "Directory: $dir\tRemote: $remote\n
done
```

I've tried using:

- `column` (which formats each line separately, as it's a for loop)
- `printf`  (`printf "Directory: %s Remote: %s\n" "$dir" "$remote"`)
- `awk` (`echo "Directory: $dir Remote: $remote" | awk '{printf ("%s-20s %s-20s %s-20s %s-20s",$1 $2 $3 $4)}'`)

Among many other variations of these commands.

I'm probably missing something basic (I tried my best at looking at other examples online and reading the `man` pages), but I couldn't get it to work.

I'd really appreciate any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`column` should work just fine.
However, you don't add it to each loop iteration, but in the end:

```bsh
for
...
done | column -t
```

Output:

```
Directory:  /some/long/directory/path  Remote:  some-remote
Directory:  /some/dir/path             Remote:  other-remote
```

---

Some additional notes regarding your script:

- Do not loop `find` output like this. [Check here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice).
- Quote file/directory variables --> `cd "$dir"`
- Do not use Variables in `printf` `FORMAT` string. --> `printf 'Directory: %s\tRemote: %s\n' "$dir" "$remote"`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `column`, but

- you have to feed it the *overall* loop output instead of the per-iteration output, and
- you should avoid [iterating over the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Since you indicate that your shell is `bash`, you can instead use the `globstar` and `nullglob` (and, as noted by @Kusalananda, the `dotglob`) options to iterate directly from the shell:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s dotglob
for d in **/.git/
do
  cd "$d"
  printf "Directory: %s\tRemote: %s\n" "${d%/.git/}" "$(git remote)"
  cd - >/dev/null
done | column -t -s $'\t'
```

- The `globstar` option enables the `**` glob (aka "wildcard") that matches any depth of intermediate directories, thereby allowing you to descend into the directory tree within a loop.
- The `nullglob` option will ensure that you don't iterate at all if there is no matching directory. Without it, the glob pattern will be taken as refering to a directory with *literal name* `**/.git/` in case no filename matches, and the loop will be executed once with this (non-sensical) value for `$d`.
- The `dotglob` option will ensure that the `**` also matches "hidden" intermediate directories (i.e. those that begin with a `.`, as in `some/directory/.path/repository`).
- Since you don't need the `.git/`-part of the path, the shell string processing directive `${d%/.git/}` will remove the last appearence of `/.git/` from the value of `$d`.
- The output within the loop is TAB-separated, so the `column` command is instructed via `-s $'\t'` to take a TAB character as input column separator rather than the default (which is space-separated columns).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this - thank you for letting me know.  If I manage to format a loop without find, I'll be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 4):

Rewriting your loop:

```bsh
find /some/path -type d -name .git -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        printf "Directory: %s@Remote: %s\n" \
            "${dirpath%/.git}" \
            "$( git -C "$dirpath" remote )"
    done' sh {} + |
column -s '@' -t
```

This uses `column` to format the output of `find`.  The `find` command finds all `.git` directories and outputs the needed info with the help of an in-line `sh -c` script that is called with batches of found directory paths.   For output, the in-line script  modifies the given directory paths to *not* include the actual `/.git` at the end, which means they would instead point to the Git project directory.

The output is tabulated with `@` characters, which `column` later uses to aligned the data.  Change the `@` in the  in-line `sh -c` script and in the call to `column` if you need to use another character.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

---

If you have Git repositories with *multiple* remotes, you may want to duplicate the output for each remote separately:

```bsh
find /some/path -type d -name .git -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        git -C "$dirpath" remote |
        while IFS= read -r remote; do
            printf "Directory: %s@Remote: %s\n" \
                "${dirpath%/.git}" "$remote"
        done
    done' sh {} + |
column -s '@' -t
```

Here, we simply read lines from `git -C "$dirpath" remote`.  Each line will contain the name of a Git remote, and for each read remote we do our output.

This may output

```
Directory: /some/path/src  Remote: origin
Directory: /some/path/src  Remote: private
```

if the repository at `/some/path/src` has two remotes.

---

Just for fun, we want JSON output:

```bsh
find /some/path -type d -name .git -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        git -C "$dirpath" remote |
        while IFS= read -r remote; do
            jo directory="${dirpath%/.git}" remote="$remote"
        done
    done' sh {} +
```

Possible output:

```json
{"directory":"/some/path/src","remote":"origin"}
{"directory":"/some/path/src","remote":"private"}
{"directory":"/some/path/yash-shell","remote":"origin"}
{"directory":"/some/path/zsh-shell","remote":"origin"}
{"directory":"/some/path/datamash","remote":"origin"}
```